# Not able to render tiny mce editor in mvc4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, tinymce, tinymce-4

I am trying to render a tinymce in a partial view.

I have included the reference to tinmce

```
<script src="~/Scripts/tinymce/js/tinymce/tinymce.js"></script>
<script>
 tinymce.init({
        selector: "textarea"
});
</script>
```

On the browser I get just the textarea and not the editor. However, it works perfectly when I write the same code in another dummy application with partial view.
I am using MVC 4.

Kindly suggest.

Comment: Per dombenoit below, you may be not getting to your tinymce.js script.  If you install the Firebug extension on Firefox (similar functionality on Chrome exists), you can click on the "console" tab and see if you are getting a 404 or any other javascript error.

Comment: Checked in chrome as well as firebug, not getting any error, and the tinymce js gets included properly :(

Answer (score 0):

I bet that script leads to a 404. Either remove the tilde or use `@Url.Content`.

```
<script src="/Scripts/tinymce/js/tinymce/tinymce.js"></script>
<script>
 tinymce.init({
        selector: "textarea"
});
</script>
```

Or

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/tinymce/js/tinymce/tinymce.js")"></script>
<script>
 tinymce.init({
        selector: "textarea"
});
</script>
```

Comment: Yeah I checked that but the JS gets included perfectly and the source path is able to open the JS in new tab too and no console errors.